# Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor with tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I want to create Tensorflow dataset using `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` but I got this error:
`Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor`.

To simplify the issue, I took the following example which is similar to my data:

```
import tensorflow as tf
 
data =  ['A', 'B']

label  = [ ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'] , ['b1', 'b2', 'b3' , 'b4' ] ]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data , label))
```

This problem appears because the lists in label are not equal, `len(['a1', 'a2', 'a3']) not equal len(['b1', 'b2', 'b3' , 'b4' ]).`
I want to keep the data as it is without using padding.
I tried `tf.ragged.constant` and other solutions in this site but it did not work with me.

Comment: Maybe use `from_generator` on the zipped data and labels instead?

Comment: @ShlomiF, I tried it but give me this error:  TypeError: `generator` must be a Python callable. Can you give me simple example? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work,

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data , tf.ragged.constant(label)))

for data in dataset.as_numpy_iterator():
    print(data)

#outputs
(b'A', array([b'a1', b'a2', b'a3'], dtype=object))
(b'B', array([b'b1', b'b2', b'b3', b'b4'], dtype=object))
```